# Inputting UTF-8 characters into the Bash CLI

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a directory listing with files like:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 2011-01-11 21:06 Капкан
drwxr-xr-x   3 nobody nogroup       4096 2011-11-17 08:40 СБПЧ
```

When I copy/paste or directly input such filenames into the prompt, I expect to be able to work with them just like Latin-1 letters.

Instead, I get results like:

```
# Pasting "Капкан"
$ :?апкан
```

You see the first letter is replaced by "`:?`". Then, I am not able to traverse the characters to the left except by deleting them. Keyboard-based input produces the same results. `tmux` or `screen` yank/paste produces the same results.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this situation! This is a pretty old Debian distro (`$ uname -a
Linux weezy 2.6.37.6.RNx86_32.1.4 #1 Thu Jul 26 04:49:29 PDT 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`), but still I'd think that there's a way to get UTF-8 filenames behaving as I'd expect.

I am using OS X's `Terminal.app` and `TERM` is set to `xterm-color`.

I do believe these filenames are encoded using UTF-8. I am using Bash 3.1.17, and here is my output from `locale`:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Here's my output from `$ locale -a`:

```
C
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
ko_KR.utf8
nl_NL.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
zh_TW.utf8
```

I would consider installing `ru_RU.UTF-8` from `/etc/locale.gen` but I'm having trouble with basic Latin characters too, like `á`.

Comment: That's what you get if you copy the letters from the terminal and try to paste them back? What terminal is this?

Comment: This also happens with direct input, not just pasting. I am using OS X's `Terminal.app`, and I've got `TERM` set to `xterm-color`.

Comment: If this was xterm itself I'd suggest checking the various input settings for utf-8/eight-bit-input but I don't know if Terminal.app has those (I'd sort of hope not). Can you paste these characters into other applications correctly when copied from the terminal?

Comment: Yep, pasting out works fine: that's how I got those characters into this post. The problem, anyway, is _both_ with direct input and copy/paste, both OS copy/paste and `tmux` vi-mode yank/paste. Amusingly, when I mount that path locally via SSHFS, I'm able to use my local Bash as expected: Input+autocomplete, AND copy/paste.

Comment: Do you have the `Escape non-ASCII characters` setting in Terminal.app enabled or disabled? If it is enabled does disabling it help?

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. It was disabled, and I enabled it, and now it works "normally". I don't understand what Terminal.app was doing before, what this setting does, and why I didn't experience the phenomenon locally. Do you know why? Care to post an answer? Would gladly vote-up and accept.

Comment: To clarify what I mean by "works normall": with this setting _enabled_, I can copy/paste non-7-bit letters. I can also switch OS X to Cyrillic input, type a letter, hit tab and get autocomplete.

Comment: What do you get if you run `ls > OUTPUT` and then edit the file in vim and hit `ga` and `g8` on that `К` character? This sounds like your output/input isn't actually UTF-8 to me (as I would have expected that setting to work the other way if it was.

Comment: Hah! Before posting I was trying to figure out a good way to do what you describe. For some reason `ls > OUTPUT` didn't occur to me :|. Anyway, this is indeed UTF-8: `d0 9a` is that `K` (http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). Thanks for introducing me to `ga` and `g8`. Wasn't aware of those! Had been using `hexdump`.

Comment: I almost suggested xxd or hexdump but couldn't come up with as clear directions for using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments above twiddling the Terminal.app `Escape non-ASCII characters` setting appears to have solved the problem. Though I am left confused at to the direction in which the twiddling was necessary to make this work correctly.